# If $\mu$ is ergodic measure with full support, then it is unique?

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

> Let $T : X\to X$ be a continuous transformation on a compact metric
> space $X$ and let $\mu$ be an invariant Borel probability measure for
> $T$ (i.e., $\mu(T^{-1}(A)) = \mu(A)$ for all Borel sets $A$), which is
> ergodic (that is, if $T^{-1}(A) = A$, then $\mu(A)\in\{0,1\}$). Assume
> that $\mu$ has full support, i.e., $\operatorname{supp}(\mu) = X$.
> Does it then follow that $\mu$ is the unique ergodic measure?

Well, suppose that there exists another ergodic measure $\nu$ for $T$ on $X$. Then I know that $\mu$ and $\nu$ must be mutually singular. That is, there exist sets $E,F\subset X$ such that $E\cap F = \emptyset$ and $\mu(E) = \nu(F) = 1$. But from there I can't infer a contradiction. And, more, the statement does not hold for arbitrary measures $\mu$ and $\nu$. For example, consider $X = [0,1]$ with $\mu=$ Lebesgue measure and $\nu=\delta_0$. Then $\mu$ and $\nu$ are mutually singular and $\mu$ has full support.

What I can show is that the support of $\nu$ is a $\mu$-null set and has empty interior. But that's all. Or is that maybe all about it, and such ergodic measures can coexist?

Comment: I'm curious about why you say the support of $\nu$ has empty interior.

Comment: @LeeMosher Hell, I was wrong. My thoughts were the following: By the assumption on its support, $\mu$ is completely positive, i.e., $\mu(U)>0$ for each non-empty open $U$. Let $M$ be the support of $\nu$. Then it is not difficult to show that $TM\subset M$, and hence $\mu(M)\in\{0,1\}$. If $\mu(M)=1$, then $\mu(X\backslash M) = 0$. But $X\backslash M$ is open, so $M=X$ follows. I thought that this is a contradiction (which then would imply $\mu(M) = 0$, and thus $\operatorname{int}(M) = \emptyset$). However, it may well be that two mutually singular measures both have full support.

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked, although constructing examples in the dynamical setting of your post is much harder than the answer given by @AlpUzman.

Comment: The key words here are *unique ergodicity* versus *non-unique ergodicity*.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for your reply. I guess it's not true that a unique ergodic measure on $X$ must have full support, right?

Comment: That's an entirely different question.

Comment: @LeeMosher Sure it is. But do you have an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

> For example, consider $X = [0,1]$ with $\mu=$ Lebesgue measure and $\nu=\delta_0$. Then $\mu$ and $\nu$ are mutually singular and $\mu$ has full support.

Both of those measures are invariant and ergodic w/r/t $T:x\mapsto 2x \mod{1}$.

Comment: Thank you, Alp!